# grep and valid parenthesis sequence

Tags: regex, grep

I need to extract all indices from my latex files. But some indices may look like this

> \index{*3*sqrt*uppersqrt{\hspace{-2.5pt}$\uppersqrt{\;\;\;}$(upper
>   square root)}}

So i need to somehow count in regex number of currently opened curly brackets. I don't know how to handle such a case.

Also, if index contain `/` then i don't need such index.

Example:

```
Anything before. \index{{}{}}\index{Hi}\anothertag{something}
\index{}{}
\index{/}
```

expected result is

```
\index{{}{}}
\index{Hi}
\index{}
```

Comment: For the first case doesn't a greedy dot work for you? `\\index{.*}`

Comment: @revo i think it can match several indices together

Comment: What part do you call an index?

Comment: @revo Whole such expression, but there is may be any text after such an expression.

Comment: This is *fundamentally* something `grep` is badly suited to do: [regular expressions famously cannot count](http://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/1968). Now, `grep`’s query language isn’t entirely regular but it’s a good approximation of when (not) to use `grep` and similar tools.

Comment: Are you able to use `grep -P`?

Comment: @revo yes, probably you mean recursion:) At least it is listed when i run `grep --help`

Comment: We need more information about trailing and leading data. What things could be before a `\index` and after its index syntax `{..}`? Is `\index` literal string or changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
\\index({(?(?!{|})[^\/{}]*|(?1))*})
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nE4cL5/1)

Explanation:

```
\\index             # Match `\index` literally
(                   # Start of capturing group (1)
    {                   # Match opening brace `{`
    (?                  # Start of conditional statement
        (?!{|})             # If very next immediate character is not `{` or `}`
        [^\/{}]*            # Anything except these characters
        |                   # Else
        (?1)                # Recurs capturing group (1)
    )*                  # End of conditional - repeat conditional zero or more times - greedily.
    }                   # Match closing brace `}`
)                   # End of capturing group (1)
```

Usage:

```
grep -Po "\\index({(?(?!{|})[^\/{}]*|(?1))*})" input_file.txt
```

Output based on input provided by OP:

```
\index{{}{}}
\index{Hi}
\index{}
```

Comment: What about this `\index{{}{{}{{{{{}{}}}}}{}}}`?

Comment: What is expected?

Comment: i think it is a valid sequence and should be matched. FYI, i voted up, because you information was useful.

Comment: Well, [**it matches**](https://regex101.com/r/nE4cL5/2). What's the problem in your side?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited number of brackets that can be opened? 
The regex

```
\\index{(?:[^{]|(?:{(?:[^{]|(?:{[^{]*}))*}))*}
```

Will match a max of 3 brackets deep, like: \index{{{}}{{}}}